# Prints a 2D list of the possible rolls of two dice in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print a 2D list of the possible rolls of two dice in python 3.0+, using Eclipse
I have two questions. First, why my prof gave the function that take no arguments, what should I write for the main program?
Second, when it runs to r.append(result) , it said AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' 
Can anyone helps me please, Thank you so much
functions:

```
def roll_two_dice():
"""
-------------------------------------------------------
Prints a 2D list of the possible rolls of two dice.
-------------------------------------------------------
Postconditions:
    prints
    a table of possible dice rolls
-------------------------------------------------------
"""
r = []
rolls = []
for r in range(DICE1):
    for c in range(DICE2):
        result = r + c + 1
        r.append(result)
    rolls.append(r)
    r = []
print("{}".format(rolls))


main program

from functions import roll_two_dice

roll_two_dice()
```

the result should look like this

Table of Two Dice Rolls

```
  [[2    3    4    5    6    7]  ............. [7    8    9   10   11   12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to do your homework, but to answer your questions:

1) Probably because your Professor wanted to make the assignment more challenging

2) Because when you are trying to append `r`, `r` is an int

```
for r in range(DICE1):  # r are the integers in the range of the 1st die
    for c in range(DICE2):
        result = r + c + 1
        r.append(result)  # you are trying to append result to said integer
```

Think about how you name and rename your variables as you change the types throughout the script.

Comment: oh,!!!!! right!!! I used 'r' for two different things!!! I was so stupid! Thanks a lot!!!